# При нажатии на лайк в RecyclerView мгновенно перекидывает на начало страницы

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, firebase

У меня есть лента RecyclerView, которая содержит посты или же объявления как в соцсетях, но при нажатии на кнопку лайка меня перебрасывает на начало RecyclerView. Код ленты содержится во фрагменте, ниже приведены код функционала и код макета одного поста в xml

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    DatabaseReference mDataBase;
    RecyclerView rv;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    ArrayList<Announcment> announcements;
    ArrayList<String> keys;
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        init(view);
        getUrlAnnouncement();
        return view;
    }

    public void init(View view) {
        mDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Announcements");
        rv = view.findViewById(R.id.rvHome);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        rv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        announcements = new ArrayList<>();
        keys = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(announcements, getContext());
    }

    public void loadProduct() {
//        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(announcements, getContext());
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void getUrlAnnouncement() {
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
//                if (announcements.size() > 0) {
//                    announcements.clear();
//                }
                ArrayList<Announcment> newAnnouncements = new ArrayList<>();

                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Announcment ancmnt = ds.getValue(Announcment.class);
                    newAnnouncements.add(ancmnt);
//                    announcements.add(ancmnt);

                    keys.add(ds.getKey());
                    loadProduct();
                }

                announcements.clear();
                announcements.addAll(newAnnouncements);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        };
        mDataBase.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
    }

    public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.AnnouncementViewHolder> {
        private ArrayList<Announcment> adapterAnnouncements;
        private Context context;

        public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Announcment> adapterAnnouncements, Context context) {
            this.adapterAnnouncements = adapterAnnouncements;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecyclerViewAdapter.AnnouncementViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.announc_item, parent, false);
            AnnouncementViewHolder avh = new AnnouncementViewHolder(v);
            return avh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewAdapter.AnnouncementViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.nickName.setText(adapterAnnouncements.get(position).getNickName());
            holder.announcement_time.setText(adapterAnnouncements.get(position).getAnnouncement_time());
            holder.announcement_title.setText(adapterAnnouncements.get(position).getAnnouncement_title());
            holder.announcement_votes.setText(Integer.toString(adapterAnnouncements.get(position).getAnnouncement_votes()));
            holder.announcement_comments_count.setText(Integer.toString(adapterAnnouncements.get(position).getAnnouncement_comments_count()));
            Picasso.get().load(adapterAnnouncements.get(position).getProfile_avatar()).into(holder.profile_avatar);
            Picasso.get().load(adapterAnnouncements.get(position).getMain_announcement()).into(holder.main_announcement);

            if (adapterAnnouncements.get(position).isVoted == true) {
                holder.participate_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.man_icon_blue);
                holder.announcement_votes.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0096D7"));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return adapterAnnouncements.size();
        }

        class AnnouncementViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView nickName, announcement_time, announcement_title, announcement_votes, announcement_comments_count;
            ImageView profile_avatar, main_announcement, participate_button;

            public AnnouncementViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                nickName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nickName);
                announcement_time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.announcement_time);
                announcement_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.announcement_title);
                announcement_votes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.announcement_votes);
                announcement_comments_count = itemView.findViewById(R.id.announcement_comments_count);
                profile_avatar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_avatar);
                main_announcement = itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_announcement);
                participate_button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView6);

                participate_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int positionIndex = getAdapterPosition();
                        mDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Announcements").child(keys.get(positionIndex));
                        Announcment announcement = adapterAnnouncements.get(positionIndex);
                        if (announcement.isVoted == false) {
                            mDataBase.child("announcement_votes").setValue(announcement.announcement_votes + 1);
                            mDataBase.child("isVoted").setValue(true);
                            announcement.isVoted = true;
                            participate_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.man_icon_blue);
                            announcement_votes.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0096D7"));
                        } else if (announcement.isVoted == true) {
                            mDataBase.child("announcement_votes").setValue(announcement.announcement_votes - 1);
                            mDataBase.child("isVoted").setValue(false);
                            announcement.isVoted = false;
                            participate_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.man_icon);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Код для макета:

````
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="310dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_avatar"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nickName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="nickName"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profile_avatar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/announcement_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
        android:text="5 ч"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/main_announcement"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_announcement"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_avatar"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/announcement_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="174dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="175dp"
        android:text="Title text"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_announcement" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_announcement"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/man_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/announcement_votes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/announcement_comments"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/announcement_votes"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_announcement"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/comment_button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/announcement_comments_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/announcement_comments" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/announcement_menu_button"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_announcement"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/three_dots" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>```
````